# Android TabLayout Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-sdk-tools

In my android application, in tab layout, sometimes it throws some error/exception which mentioned below:

**"No field view in class Lcom/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout$g; (declaration of 'com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$g' appears in base.apk) Exception Class: class java.lang.NoSuchFieldException"**

I tried by updating the library to latest --> com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
but still it throwing the same exception,

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Try [reinstalling the android sdk](https://frameboxxindore.com/android/how-do-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-android-sdk.html).

Comment: Thanks,. Alias Cartellano,. it may useful on local code,. please can you tell how it works on multiple repositories.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "multiple repositories"?

Comment: In case: multiple resource are working on same code,.by reinstalling the sdk must reflect only in my IDE,.there will not any changes reflected on git as well,.
in this case how to i handle this issue.